# Quick technique for comparing images better than MSE in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, similarity, ssim

I have been using Structural Similarity Index (through tensorflow) for comparing images, however it takes too long. I was wondering if there is an alternative technique that doesn't take so much time. It is also okay if someone could point out a more efficient implementation of SSIM than tensorflow in Python.

My intention for using SSIM, is that given a reference image (A) and a *set* of images (B), I need to understand which image in B is the most similar to the reference image A.

Comment: Have you tried `ssim` from skimage? IDK, but is there any difference with `tf`'s implementation?

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23983459/9215780

Comment: Thank you but I am not looking to check if they are exactly identical. I'd like to compare them using a certain metric that outputs a score.

Comment: we don't know how you want the images compared. what are you going to use this score matrix for?

Comment: @Mikah Thank you for the comment. I have made the changes. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you looked at aHash, which is one of the hashing algorithms in ImageHash?  I can compare 100 images in approx. 0.29 of a second.  When I tried the same test using skimage it's about 1.2 seconds.

Comment: I have not looked into that, but I will soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 01-02-2021**

I decided to explore some other Python modules that could be used for Image comparison.  I also wanted to use *concurrent.futures*, which I hadn't used before.

I created two **GitGub Gists** with the code that I wrote.

[skimage ssim image comparison](https://gist.github.com/johnbumgarner/13045fb36d215efa65d55f5a940ee823)

[ImageHash aHash image comparison](https://gist.github.com/johnbumgarner/265f3137592a3cf5ba670e84ae404e65)

The ImageHash module was able to compare 100 images in 0.29 of a second and the skimage module took 1.2 seconds for the same task.

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

I haven't tested the speed of the code in this answer, because I have only used the code in some image testing that I posted to GitHub:

[facial similarities](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/facial_similarities)

[facial prediction](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/facial_prediction)

The code below will produce a similarity score between reference image (A) and set of images (B).

The complete code is located [in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/facial_similarities/blob/master/numpy_math_module_image_comparison.py)

```
import os
from os import walk
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from math import *


def get_image_files(directory_of_images):
    """
     This function is designed to traverse a directory tree and extract all
     the image names contained in the directory.
    :param directory_of_images: the name of the target directory containing
           the images to be trained on.
    :return: list of images to be processed.
    """
    images_to_process = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory_of_images):
        for filename in filenames:
            accepted_extensions = ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.svg', '.tiff')
            if filename.endswith(accepted_extensions):
                images_to_process.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        return images_to_process


def pre_process_images(image_one, image_two, additional_resize=False, max_image_size=1000):
    """
     This function is designed to resize the images using the Pillow module.
    :param image_one: primary image to evaluate against a secondary image
    :param image_two: secondary image to evaluate against the primary image
    :param additional_resize:
    :param max_image_size: maximum allowable image size in pixels
    :return: resized images
    """
    lower_boundary_size = (min(image_one.size[0], image_two.size[0]), min(image_one.size[1], image_two.size[1]))
    # reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize
    # reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#PIL.Image.LANCZOS
    image_one = image_one.resize(lower_boundary_size, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    image_two = image_two.resize(lower_boundary_size, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    if max(image_one.size) > max_image_size and additional_resize:
        resize_factor = max_image_size / max(image_one.size)
        image_one = image_one.resize((int(lower_boundary_size[0] * resize_factor),
                                      int(lower_boundary_size[1] * resize_factor)), resample=Image.LANCZOS)

        image_two = image_two.resize((int(lower_boundary_size[0] * resize_factor),
                                      int(lower_boundary_size[1] * resize_factor)), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    return image_one, image_two


def get_ssim_similarity(image_one_name, image_two_name, window_size=7, dynamic_range=255):
    """
    The Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) is a method for measuring the similarity between two images.
    The SSIM index can be viewed as a quality measure of one of the images being compared, provided the
    other image is regarded as of perfect quality.
    :param image_one_name: primary image to evaluate against a secondary image
    :param image_two_name: secondary image to evaluate against the primary image
    :param window_size: The side-length of the sliding window used in comparison. Must be an odd value.
    :param dynamic_range: Dynamic range of the input image, specified as a positive scalar.
    The default dynamic range is 255 for images of data type uint8.
    :return: computational score and image names
    """
    image_one = Image.open(image_one_name)
    image_two = Image.open(image_two_name)

    if min(list(image_one.size) + list(image_two.size)) < 7:
        raise Exception("One of the images was too small to process using the SSIM approach")
    image_one, image_two = pre_process_images(image_one, image_two, True)
    image_one, image_two = image_one.convert('I'), image_two.convert('I')
    c1 = (dynamic_range * 0.01) ** 2
    c2 = (dynamic_range * 0.03) ** 2
    pixel_length = window_size ** 2
    ssim = 0.0
    adjusted_width = image_one.size[0] // window_size * window_size
    adjusted_height = image_one.size[1] // window_size * window_size
    for i in range(0, adjusted_width, window_size):
        for j in range(0, adjusted_height, window_size):
            crop_box = (i, j, i + window_size, j + window_size)
            crop_box_one = image_one.crop(crop_box)
            crop_box_two = image_two.crop(crop_box)
            np_array_one, np_array_two = np.array(crop_box_one).flatten(), np.array(crop_box_two).flatten()
            np_variable_one, np_variable_two = np.var(np_array_one), np.var(np_array_two)
            np_average_one, np_average_two = np.average(np_array_one), np.average(np_array_two)
            cov = (np.sum(np_array_one * np_array_two) - (np.sum(np_array_one) *
                                                          np.sum(crop_box_two) / pixel_length)) / pixel_length
            ssim += ((2.0 * np_average_one * np_average_two + c1) * (2.0 * cov + c2)) / \
                    ((np_average_one ** 2 + np_average_two ** 2 + c1) * (np_variable_one + np_variable_two + c2))
    similarity_percent = (ssim * pixel_length / (adjusted_height * adjusted_width)) * 100
    return round(similarity_percent, 2)


target_image = 'a.jpg'
image_directory = 'b_images'

images = get_image_files(image_directory)

for image in images:
    ssim_result = get_ssim_similarity(target_image, image)
```

I would also recommend looking at the *Python* module [ImageHash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash). I have multiple code examples and test cases [published here](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/facial_similarities#imagehash-library).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post a working example of this. I tried running the code but I am encountering errors -

Comment: import numpy as np;
import tensorflow as tf;
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='mnist.npz'
);
a,b = pre_process_images(x_train[1], x_train[2] , additional_resize=False, max_image_size=1000);
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I added all the code for this example.  All my code is in script numpy_math_module_image_comparison in the repository that I mentioned.

Comment: @desert_ranger my code does not use tensorflow, so the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" is not from my code example.